# Inertia returns 404 when deploying to hostinger

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a laravel 10 project that utilizes inertia using vue 3. I transferred/copied all the public files in the `public_html` folder in the root directory (including the build folder). I also run `npm run build` on my local machine for asset building for production. When I access the site, there is this wierd `/public` path everytime I access then it shows this

`Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/404.vue.`

the `404.vue` must be rendered since I dont have a `/public` route defined. but still if i try another url its the same error.

In my `app.blade.php` i have this configuration

```
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
    @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
    </body>
```

htaccess (public_html)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I also updated `index.php` and added the project folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue: I deployed to a shared hosting and I got the 404 for app.js and app.css when accessing the home page.

My solution was to change the content of .htaccess that was on the project root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on     
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]     
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete hot file from the public root folder

Comment: I dont have a hot file or a folder.

Comment: @draw134 have you found a solution for that? I faced the same thing using React. So, when accessing the website it says: www.domain/js/app.js is not found and www.domain/css/app.css is not found

Comment: @Crane, honestly i forgot how i solved it, but i checked the code. can you replace your vite directive using this `@vite('resources/js/app.js')` in your main layout?

Comment: @draw134 I found another solution for this error. In my case my .htaccess was wrong. I had to use this code: 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
`
It worked perfectly. Thanks so much for answering.

Comment: good to hear buddy @Crane. Could you add your solution here as answer? So other people also know it and try

Comment: For sure, dude. Will do.